# How do I modify a value in xml file stored inside isolated storage?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

I'm creating a windows phone 7 app and I'm having a bit of a trouble with changing values in my xml-file, which is located inside isolated storage.
My method is here:

```
public void updateItemValueToIsoStorage(string id, 
                                        string itemAttribute, 
                                        string value)
{
    using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = isoStorage.OpenFile(
                           "items.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);
            //According to given parameters, 
            //set the correct attribute to correct value.
            var data = from c in xml.Descendants("item")
                       where c.Attribute("id").Value == id
                       select c;
            foreach (Object i in data) 
            {

                xml.Root.Attribute(itemAttribute).SetValue(value);

            }                
        }
    }
}
```

And my xml-file inside isolated storage looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
<item id="0" title="Milk" image="a.png" lastbought="6" lastingtime="6" />
<item id="1" title="Cheese" image="b.png" lastbought="2" lastingtime="20" />
<item id="2" title="Bread" image="c.png" lastbought="3" lastingtime="8" />
</items>
```

I get a NullReferenceException from this line:

```
xml.Root.Attribute(itemAttribute).SetValue(value);
```

Any ideas how I should do it then?
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `xml.Root.Attribute` in your loop which is trying to find the attribute on the root element - where it doesn't exist. You're also completely ignoring the `i` variable in your iterator.

I think you meant:

```
var data = from c in xml.Descendants("item")
           where (string) c.Attribute("id") == id
           select c;

foreach (XElement element  in data)
{
    element.Attribute(itemAttribute).SetValue(value);
}
```

Note that by using the explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `string` in the query, there won't be an exception if there are any `item` elements which don't have the `id` attribute.

It's worth noting that this has nothing to do with Windows Phone 7 or isolated storage really - you'd get exactly the same error with your original code using the desktop framework from a console app, even with the XML hard-coded. For similar situations, it's worth trying to reproduce and debug the problem in a desktop setting, as it's typically quicker than using the emulator or a real device.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working. I wonder what kind of a brain freeze I had there. Thanks.